# WP_Query debug in ajax call to avoid 500

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How do I debug

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

It's in functions.php file and called using AJAX admin-ajax.php:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
  data: data,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
```

Doing it like:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 'posts_per_page' => -1));
var_dump($loop);
exit();
```

... simply gives 500 internal error in response.

**EDIT**: The error is in Query due to `posts_per_page => -1`. I was able to see the dump after changing -1 to 1 by personal judgement. But I am still so curios to know how do I debug an incorrect query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only adding `var_dump($loop);exit();` causes error? Have you looked into log file?

Comment: Tip: You can use the `network` tab in your browser's console, check "response" of that specific request and you'd probably see the error (in case the error_reporting is on in the server)

Comment: @OfirBaruch it's just giving me 500 internal error over there.

Comment: @ankhzet no the error comes but after the WP_Query() but I think it should have stopped after exit();

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq, no, if `WP_Query(...)` caused error, then execution would just never reach that `exit()`. Try to look into log file for error reasons. Or surround `WP_Query(...)` call with `try { WP_Query(...); } catch ($e) { var_dump($e); }` to try to catch error.

Comment: also, in `array('product', product_variation')` you missed `'` at the beginning of `product_variation` string. Is it mistyped here or in the code also?

Comment: Good catch but it is fine in the code, I think it happened because Natalie editied this post. Let me do the try catch thing

Comment: Try catch did not help. See the Edit please @ankhzet

Comment: Again, look at the log file. There should be logged last error.